# Portable ImageMagick + Rails 3.0 on Windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, carrierwave, minimagick

Where to put files from [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php)

> Portable Win32 static at 16 bits-per-pixel. Just copy to your host and
> run (no installer, no Windows registry entries).

to use for carrierwave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the executables from ImageMagick be usable, they need to be added to the `PATH` variable (so convert.exe and identify.exe work)

You can do

```
SET PATH=C:\path\to\imagemagick;%PATH%
```

Which will ensure these files are in the PATH before others. Check that the above mentioned executables needs to be present **in that directory**, if they are inside another one (like bin) use that directory instead.

Both CarrierWave and Paperclip will use the tools from the PATH, so set the path first and then start your Rails application.

Hope that helps.